# How to detect click outside the div in jquery

Tags: jquery

I search for it and find so many answer and none of worked as I am still new to JQuery. Actually I am creating a whack a animal game and I have to detect the click outside he image and if user clicked outside the image then it decrements the score by 10. I tried so many things but none of work. You can see the code at:-
As I think you have to understand this by running the code. 
https://github.com/ayushcs/molegame

[image]

I am providing the Html structure :

```
<div class="game_top">
            <div id="wrap" class="wrap">
                <div class="gamewrap">
                    <div class="hole hole_1"><img src="wack.gif" class="wack" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="thing thing_1" id="thing_1">
                        //In this thing class images are coming dynamically.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--end_hole_1-->
                    <div class="hole hole_2"><img src="wack.gif" class="wack" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="thing thing_2" id="thing_2">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--end_hole_2-->
                    <div class="hole hole_3"><img src="wack.gif" class="wack" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="thing thing_3" id="thing_3">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--end_hole_3-->
                    <div class="hole hole_4"><img src="wack.gif" class="wack" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="thing thing_4" id="thing_4">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--end_hole_4-->
                    <div class="hole hole_5"><img src="wack.gif" class="wack" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="thing thing_5" id="thing_5">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--end_hole_5-->
                </div>
                <!--gamewrap-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="game_bottom">
        </div>
```

Comment: Actually if you see the image clearly then on the gamewrap there is a div hole so it will not work.

Comment: Actually the img has the position absolute so that would no t work I tried it already

Comment: Yes and to stop event bubbling we have to use stoppropagation but it basically ruin the dom

Comment: Always useful to add relevant information after someone tries to help you; please don't do that - add it in the question.   "I can't do A" - "do B, it will fix it" - "ah but *actually* that won't work because of some unrelated thing I didn't bother to tell you earlier" - not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code:

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    var container = $("#imageContainer"); //it should be your image id

    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        //decrement score here by 10 marks
    } else {
        //Increment score here by 10 marks.
    }
});
```

Hope this helps you.

I have checked your code. Please replace below function and check if it works for you:

```
function MakeGameBoard() {
  var things = 5;
  var code = "";

  for (var thing = 1; thing < things + 1; thing++) {
      code = '<div class="img-game" id="img_' + thing + '"> <img src="" class="img-block"/>  </div>';
    $('#thing_' + thing).html(code);
  }

  $('.yellow-block').mouseup(function() {
    score = score + 15;
  });


  var fairTouch = 0; 
  $('.img-block').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    fairTouch = 1;
    var nav = $(this);
    if (nav.length) {
      var contentNav = nav.offset().top;
      if($(this).attr('src')=='animal_2.png'){
        score=score+15;
      } else if (contentNav > 270 && contentNav <= 361){
        score = score + 5;
      } else if (contentNav > 225 && contentNav <= 270) {
        score = score + 10;
      } else if (contentNav >= 204 && contentNav <= 225) {
        score = score + 15;
      } else alert("ye");
    }
  });
    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        if (fairTouch != 1) {
            console.log('reducing');
            score = score - 15;
            if (score < 0) {
                score = 0;
            }
            Wackathing();
        } 
        fairTouch  = 0;
    });

}
```

It should work fine for you.

Comment: No its not working if I clicked on image its also detecting that I am clicking outside the image . I think you doesn't see => https://github.com/ayushcs/molegame
Please suggest what I do as I am stuck at this point since previous week and got no solution how can I find?

Comment: I have updated my answer with function update. it should work fine as I have tested it on my machine and it is working fine. Happy coding my friend.

Comment: My reputation is less than 15 so it will don’t show publicly